# I, Dave, confirm that I have read the document thoroughly and accept your offer letter

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

I, Dave, confirm that I have read the document thoroughly **and accept your offer letter**.

OR

I, Dave, confirm that I have read the document thoroughly **and accepted your offer letter.**

OR

I, Dave, confirm that I have read the document thoroughly **and have accepted your offer letter.**

Which of the foregoing sentences above is acceptable, and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're responding to the offer for the first time, the first sentence is what you want. You read the document (past tense) and you're telling the recipient that, having done so, you are now accepting the offer (present tense).

If somehow your acceptance got lost and you're asked about it, you could use the second sentence (or the third, but the second is better). Then your acceptance is in the past. If this is the case, be polite. You don't know why your original acceptance never got to the recipient.

By the way, you accept the offer, not the offer letter (that you accepted when you opened the envelope).